# I need an Idiom about improving a bad situation

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing an essay about overcoming a hard time and staying motivated through it. I want an idiom to be the title. What should it be?

It could also be about bringing down something bad, like: "The Abolition of Adversity"

Comment: Well, there's the old idiomatic expression "make the best out of a bad situation".  Not sure that's what you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your essay could be titled  "Be The Light Against Darkness."

Answer (score 1):

*"When the going gets tough, the tough get going!"*

> Said to emphasize that when conditions become difficult, strong people
> take action.  [Cambridge
> Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/when-the-going-gets-tough-the-tough-get-going)

Comment: It’s an excellent suggestion. But be aware of your audience before deciding to use it. The idiom can sound glib and arrogantly dismissive of much normal human behaviour. It is popular with those who are really saying “Stop complaining, just do it my way”.

Answer (score 0):

"Make lemonade out of lemons"

but it might be long for a title

Answer (score 0):

There will always be "light at the end of the tunnel"

> signs of improvement in a situation that has been bad for a long time, or signs that a long and difficult piece of work is almost finished

[[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/light-at-the-end-of-the-tunnel)

Answer (score 0):

-In the end, "We will have a triumph worth every ounce of our effort."

-This will be an uphill battle.

-Whatever the vicissitudes, we will come through.

-It's always darkest before dawn.